# Comparing date ranges with JQuery?

Tags: jquery, date, compare

I have an option list.

I have a fixed date to go by, for example 2012-01-01.
Option list, the monthly intervals:
eg
2-10 months
7-15 months
11-25 months
14-25 months
18-30 months
30-100 months

I have seen option lists that change the content depending on what you choose in the other lists / other.

Now I would like to have an option list that shows only some choice in my option list, whichever the user specifies in the date box. If the user eg enter 2013-01-01, all choices should appear to match 2012-01-01, that is 7-15 months and 11-25 months.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Can you clarify I'm a bit confused?

Comment: Well...I have a selectlist where I fetch the options from my db. I want to show the options based on what date the user chooses, the date is an input and has the format 2010-01-01. As the example states, two of the options would be in the date range 7-15 and 11-25 months, and I would lika the two options to show if that is the case, if the user changes the date, some new options should appear.

Answer (score 0):

you should find happiness with [DateJs](http://www.datejs.com/) ans its clear API to find the number of month to the first date. Then you can know which option of the select to choose based on this value